# How to make an image carousel with vue using a photo api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to vue and looking to make a image carousel using photos from an api. I can display the photos by using:

```
<section class="images">
      <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.id":src="image.assets.large.url">
     </section>
```

but not sure how to incorporate it in to:

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete response, but it's a start, that can be improved by more experienced users:

As you'll see, your alt text needs customizing to display "First slide","Second slide" etc. and I'm not quite sure about `<img :src""`

```
<div
  id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly"
  class="carousel slide"
  data-ride="carousel"
>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <section class="images">
      <img
        v-for="image in images"
        :key="image.id"
        :src="image.assets.large.url"
      />

      <img
        class="d-block w-100"
        :src="not sure exactly about what goes here"
        alt="slide"
      />
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```